# Find the largest subset in complex parabola such that every point in the subset has a neighborhood homeomorphic to a complex open disk

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Let $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}^2:y^2=x\}$. Find the largest subset $U$ of $S$ such that for all $s\in U$, $s$ has a neighborhood $N_s$ which is homeomorphic to an open disk in $\mathbb{C}$.

If the parabola is real, then the whole parabola is homeomorphic to the real line by homeomorphism $\phi(y^2,y)=y$.
So I consider the function $f:S\to\mathbb{C}$, where $f(r^2e^{i2\theta},re^{i\theta})=re^{i\theta}$. Clearly it is a bijection.

Claim: $f$ is continuous.

Let $\epsilon>0$, and $\delta<\epsilon$. Let $(r^2e^{i2\theta},re^{i\theta})$ be a point within $\delta$ distance of $(r_0^2e^{i2\theta_0},r_0e^{i\theta_0})$. Then,

$$|(r^2e^{i2\theta},re^{i\theta})-(r_0^2e^{i2\theta_0},r_0e^{i\theta_0})|^2<\delta^2$$
$$\implies|(r^2e^{i2\theta},re^{i\theta})-(r_0^2e^{i2\theta_0},r_0e^{i\theta_0})|^2<\epsilon^2$$
$$\implies|r^2e^{i2\theta}-r_0^2e^{i2\theta_0}|^2+|re^{i\theta}-r_0e^{i\theta_0}|^2<\epsilon^2$$
$$\implies|re^{i\theta}-r_0e^{i\theta_0}|^2<\epsilon^2$$
$$\implies|re^{i\theta}-r_0e^{i\theta_0}|<\epsilon$$

What's left is to check on which subset $f^{-1}$ is continuous. The professor gave a hint that the largest subset shouldn't be the entire set. But somehow I can't find a point where $f^{-1}$ is not continuous. Any suggestions or other approaches?

Comment: Umm, $g\colon z \mapsto (z^2,z)$ is a biholomorphic map $\mathbb{C}\to S$. (Its inverse is your $f$, which is the restriction of the projection $\pi_2 \colon (w,z) \mapsto z$ to $S$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, $S$ is homeomorphic to the complex plane.

Consider the projection $\pi_2 \colon \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C},\; (w,z) \mapsto z$. This is clearly continuous, and your $f$ is the restriction of $\pi_2$ to $S$, hence also continuous. The inverse is easily given: $z \mapsto (z^2,z)$ is the inverse of $f$. Both component functions of $f^{-1}$ are continuous, hence $f^{-1}$ is continuous, and we see that $f$ is a homeomorphism. All maps considered here are even holomorphic, so $S$ is not only homeomorphic to the plane, it's biholomorphically equivalent to the plane.

Thus every point of $S$ has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to the open unit disk.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought. However the professor said "Usually when you shift from real to complex plane, either nothing happens or everything happens. If nothing happens, then I won't assign this problem." It made me believe that the answer should not be S. So I am deeply confused.

Comment: Perhaps the professor thought of the set of points having a neighbourhood $N$ such that the projection $h\colon (x,y) \mapsto x$ is a homeomorphism with a disk. Then the point $(0,0)$ is exceptional, for $h$ isn't injective on any neighbourhood of $(0,0)$. But that also happens in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so even then "nothing happens".

Comment: Why is h not injective at (0,0)?

Comment: Because every nonzero complex number has two square roots. If you look at the intersection of $S$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$, you get a parabola opened to the right, with vertex at $(0,0)$, and $h$ is the projection on the $x$-axis. Above every $x \in (0,+\infty)$ there are exactly two points of $S\cap \mathbb{R}^2$, and every neighbourhood of $0$ in $S$ contains contains $[0,\varepsilon)\times \mathbb{R}$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: So I talked to the professor. He agrees that the homeomorphism $f$ works in the complex case as in proof. However, he thinks that the neighborhood around 0 is homeomorphic to two disks glued at 0 (two square roots getting close together at 0)... I don't really agree with the two disks glued at 0 thing. But I can't think of a good argument.

Comment: OK, I've thought about it a little more... The reason that my professor keeps thinking about two disks glued at 0 is because he's drawing the disks on blackboard, a 2-d space. However, in the actual homeomorphism, the disk lives in a 4-d space. In higher dimensions, two disks can move together and become one single disk without any problem.